# Is it possible to use static values from a IValueConverter in the Converter Parameter?

Tags: silverlight, ivalueconverter

In Silverlight, I have a standard IValueConverter where I want to define the possible parameters as const strings.

```
public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public const string PARAMETER_ONE = "one";
    public const string PARAMETER_TWO  = "two";
...
```

I would then like to use the constant within the Converter Parameter, something like:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
        ConverterParameter={StaticResource BooleanConvereter.PARAMETER_TWO}" />
```

Is this possible? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both parameter and argument. Sample:

```
<converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="inversVisibConverter" Inverse="True"/>

 Visibility="{Binding ABoolValue, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource inversVisibConverter},ConverterParameter=abc}"
```

The Converter (contains both **parameter** and **argument**):

```
public sealed class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

       public bool Inverse { get; set; }

       #region Implementation of IValueConverter
        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            Visibility visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            if (value is bool)
            {
                visibility = (bool) value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            if( parameter != null )
            {
                //handle parameter here:

            }

            if (Inverse)
            {
                visibility = (visibility == Visibility.Visible) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return visibility;
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            if (!(value is Visibility)) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "VisibilityConverter can only convert from Visibility");
            }

            if (targetType == typeof(bool)) {
                return ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible) ? true : false;
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("targetType", "VisibilityConverter can only convert to Boolean");
        }
        #endregion
 }
```

Comment: While I'd prefer to use a Parameter, your solution is interesting and can solve my problem if I use the property and link it to an enum.  Then I can only use the defined enum values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Static markup extension:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static cnv:BooleanConverter.PARAMETER_ONE}}" />
```

Note that the `x:Static` needs a reference to the class itself, not your resource. Therefore you'll need to prefix it with the appropriate XML namespace prefix.

Comment: I should of mentioned that I'm working in Silverlight, I did tag it but forget to say it in the text.  From what I'm seeing, {x:Static} only works in WPF.  Is that correct?